# iisexpress: listen on external interface without modifying config file:

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-express

I want to run a WebService project with IISExpress and use the following command line to start it:

```
iisexpress.exe /path:c:\MyService /port:8000
```

That works, but the webserver is only accessible by `http://localhost:8000/MyService.asmx`

I know that I can modify the users `applicationhost.config` file to add my site and use

```
iisexpress.exe /site:MyService
```

to start it, but, if it's possible I would prefer to use the configless approach to allow external connections to iisexpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you modified HTTP.SYS to allow external traffic? Check these articles out for info on how to do that:

[How to Expose IIS Express to External Network Connections](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2011/03/22/how-to-expose-iis-express-to-external-network-connections-and-use-a-non-self-signed-certificate.aspx)

[Serving External Traffic With WebMatrix](http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx)

I've got mine serving up the site to external traffic fine, but I have modified the `applicationhost.config` file to do it. Then I have just created a .bat file to run the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /site:MySite
```

Comment: Yes, I suppose I have to use the `/site` switch. Didn't find a clue how to tell iisexpress to listen on the external interface without it. Anyway, I didn't need to modify http.sys, as mentioned in the comments of the second link, adding this line: `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="192.168.1.108:8080:" />` to the `applicationhost.config` file worked for me.